# There is a rec box with an X on some icons on my desktop. It happened after I ran a command, had to restart the computer

Tags: command-line, icons

[what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5j7d.png)[image]

[desktop icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0XZ5.jpg)[image]

So just now my system started not displaying some of the icons, and instead a red box with an x. I ran a command that I think i shouldn't have, was trying to fix an installation and am new to linux. the exact command I believe was sudo uninstall winetricks but it could be different. I was in super user mode after I had run the command sudo -i.

I'm not sure if I just deleted the images, removed my access, or have a bigger problem. Am on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Somehow, you've deleted the underlying thing. Right-Mouse-Button-Down on the icon, and select "Properties"